# (python) How to check the validity of a while loop before letting the user to input things?

Tags: python

```
import random

numberList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'jack', 'queen', 'king']
total = 0

while total <= 21:
    output = random.choice(numberList)
    if output == 'jack' or output == 'queen' or output == 'king':
        print(f'({output})')
        output = 10

    print(f'you got {output} points')
    total += output

    ask_cont = input(f'you now have {total} points, continue? [y/n]: ').lower()
    if ask_cont == 'y':
        continue
    else:
        print(f'game finished. You gain {total} points!')
        break
else:
    print(f'you lost! points exceeded = {total - 21} points!')
```

I am coding a blackjack game. However, in the while loop (condition: total amount at hand <= 21), when it **exceeded** 21 points, it still ask me to continue (ask_cont variable) or not [y/n] for **ONCE** before code finished and if I type 'n', it just give me the current points (>21) and the 'game finished' statement. How can I fix this? Thank you very much

(also, if there is any way to trim the code please comment, many thanks!)

Comment: Do `white True` at the top, and at the end of the loop do the check, like `if total > 21: print('failed'); break`.

Comment: You need to add another test after `total += output`, or it won't stop.  You could also move everything within the while after `total += output` to the top of the while.  This would make it ask at 0 points (weird) and would stop it asking after you hit >21.  The current code is weird that it will ask to hit on 21, when the answer should always be 'no'.

Comment: Just go through the code with a simple example and you will see the problem: Assume the `total` is `18`. You pick a "card" from `numberList`, e.g. a `6`. You add that value to `total`, so it is `24` now. Next, the user is asked if he wants to continue (although `total` is already `24`).

Comment: Also, you might consider two more things: First, that a player gets two cards in the beginning. Second, an ace is counted as `1` or `11`, depending on the current `total`.

Comment: @SimonFink OK thank you very much I will try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, don't worry about your code being too verbose. It's better to have long, readable code, than short, hard to decipher code. Your code looks just fine.

As far as preventing the user from continuing if `total > 21`, this is because you are adding to the total `total += output` before you get to the `while total <= 21`. To fix this, you just have two options.

The first is to have it ask at the start of the while loop, before points are added. If you do this, you would also have it ask once before the while loop starts. Normally you would do this using a `do..while` loop, but python doesn't have those.

The second optional would be to just add an extra if statement, where it only asks you to continue if `total <= 21`, otherwise it does something that finishes the game with the exceed message.